# An Attempt at AV Puzzle

Tags: visual, audio

Here's another puzzle with visuals and sound. I hope you enjoy it!

With Sound:
https://youtu.be/yHkQdEu0QpA

Static Image (the musical notes represent the music in the YouTube video):

[image: pzl.gg game]

Hint 1

> Maximum three steps to complete this puzzle

Hint 2

> The music doesn't sound like a remedy, but more like twinkle twinkle